# Javascript chain multiple function instead of passing function as argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I did a findMaxChar count algorithm practice, manage to get it to worked but my call method can be improved.

```
const myStr = 'Lorem Ipsummm'

function findRepeatable(myStr){
  let charMap = {}
  for(let char of myStr){
    if(charMap[char]) {
      charMap[char]++
    }else{
      charMap[char] = 1
    }
  }
  return charMap
}

function findMostRepeated(obj){
   let maxChar = '',
   max = 0
   for(let char in obj){
     if(obj[char] > max){
       max = obj[char]
       maxChar = char
     }
  }

  return `${maxChar}: ${max}`
}

console.log(findMostRepeated(findRepeatable(myStr)))
```

I'm passing function as argument, how can I make it to chain like this

```
findMostRepeated()
.findRepeatable()
```

https://jsbin.com/katixefoxe/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Your solution is better then chaining because chaining requires an object with state, while your solution is functional - each function knows how to do one thing without having side effects, and you can combine multiple functions to get a result.

Comment: ^ Agreed, though if you do NEED to chain it, wrap it in a class and create instance of that class

Comment: @OriDrori passing function as argument is ok? I felt it's hard to read.

Comment: If you feel it is hard to read, then assign the first result to a variable, and pass that. That is perfectly fine.

Comment: @MadelineRies - [functional programming](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) takes some getting used to. However, when you do, it's very readable, because you can see the input, and the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Many functional libraries come with a pipe function that can be used for "chaining".

```
pipe(findRepeatable, findMostRepeated)(myStr)
```

It's easy to implement yourself.

```
function pipe(...funcs) {
  return function(value) {
    for (func of funcs) {
      value = value(func)
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: or just a single line `const pipe = (...funcs) => value => funcs.reduce((v, f) => f(v), value);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 class CharMap extends Map {
  constructor(str){
    super();
    for(var char of str)
      this.add(char);
  }
  add(char){
    this.set(char, (this.get(char) || 0) + 1);
  }
  max(){
    return this.sortDesc()[0];
  }
  sortDesc(){
    return [...this].sort(([char, a], [char2, b]) => b - a);
  }
 }
```

So you can do:

```
 const map = new CharMap("abbccddeee");
 console.log(map.max());
```

To get the char and its count:

```
 const [char, count] = map.max();
```

Comment: this is way too advance haha!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const myStr = 'Lorem Ipsummm'
var myObj ={
  charMap:{},
findRepeatable:function (myStr){

  for(let char of myStr){
if(this.charMap[char]) {
  this.charMap[char]++
}else{
  this.charMap[char] = 1
}
  }
  return this;
},
findMostRepeated: function (obj){
   let maxChar = '',
   max = 0
   for(let char in this.charMap){
     if(this.charMap[char] > max){
       max = this.charMap[char]
       maxChar = char
     }
  }

  return `${maxChar}: ${max}`;
}
}
```

console.log(myObj.findRepeatable(myStr).findMostRepeated())